# Join with case query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In my query i have to check three conditions and join and where is common..but some errors in this

```
 select 
 count(case when interview_status = 1 then applicant_id else null end) as selected,
 count(case when interview_status = 2 then applicant_id else null end) as rejected,
 count(case when interview_status = 3 then applicant_id else null end) as not_attented,
 JOIN appointment ON appointment.applicant_id=student_application.applicant_id,
 WHERE filter_status=1 AND appointment_status !=0
 from student_application;
```

But this shows some errors

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN appointment ON appointment.applicant_id=student_application.applicant_id, ' at line 5

Comment: If my answer works for you, then accept it so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I see the issue with extra `,`.
2. `from` clause should be before `where`

   ```
   select 
   count(case when interview_status = 1 then applicant_id else null end) as selected,
   count(case when filter_status = 2 then applicant_id else null end) as rejected,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN FILTER_STATUS = 2 THEN APPLICANT_ID ELSE NULL END) AS NOT_ATTENTED
   from student_application
   JOIN appointment ON appointment.applicant_id=student_application.applicant_id
   WHERE FILTER_STATUS=1 AND APPOINTMENT_STATUS !=0;
   ```

Comment: Can i ask related to this answer

Comment: sure. But if it is a new question, you should better put it as a new question so that someone else might also come up with another answer.